# The argument type 'List<Food>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Food' Hive db

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I want to create a page which put selected items on favourite page, so I have found the Hive db and in it's docs I found how to do this  properly. I tried this way and now I am getting stucked, because favourite items aren't selected and put on the another page. Also I was trying another way: I created function `onFavoritePress()` and just used if-else statement inside `onPressed` function and the code looks like this:

```
 trailing: IconButton(
                         icon: getIcon(index),
                          onPressed: () {
                            if (box.containsKey(food[index].ttId)) {
                              box.delete(food[index].ttId);
                            } else {box.put(food[index].ttId, food);}
                          }));
```

But it gives the error: `The argument type 'List<Food>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Food'`
Then I changed `Box <Food> box` to `Box<dynamic> box` and this error gone, but it still dosen't work and dosen't put any items on fav's page. And I got confused what I am doing wrong.

The whole code is:
**the main:**

```
main() async {
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  await Hive.openBox<Food>(favoritesBox);
```

the 1st page:

```
class _FoodTState extends State<FoodT> {
  Box<Food> favoriteFoodBox;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    favoriteFoodBox = Hive.box(favoritesBox);
  }

 body: ValueListenableBuilder(
          valueListenable: favoriteFoodBox.listenable(),
          builder: (context, Box<Food> box, child) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: food.length,
                itemBuilder: (builder, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                      title: Text(food[index].ttTitle),
                      trailing: IconButton(
                         icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                          onPressed: () {
                            if (box.containsKey(food[index].ttId)) {
                              box.delete(food[index].ttId);
                            } else {box.put(food[index].ttId, food);}
                          }));
                });
```

**the 2d page:**

```
body: ValueListenableBuilder(
        valueListenable: favoriteFoodBox.listenable(),
        builder: (context, Box<Food> box, child) {
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: food.length,
              itemBuilder: (builder, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(food[index].ttTitle),
                  trailing: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.clear,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      favoriteFoodBox.delete(food[index].ttId);
                    },
                  ),
                );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You open the Hive box for a single `Food` item, but inside the put method, you are storing the whole list (`List<Food>`) - this is mentioned in the error message. Adjust your code and update your `put` method to store a single `Food` item:

```
trailing: IconButton(
  icon: getIcon(index),
  onPressed: () {
    if (box.containsKey(food[index].ttId)) {
      box.delete(food[index].ttId);
    } else {
      box.put(food[index].ttId, food[index]); // Changed put method
    }
}));
```

Previously, you stored the whole list, but you only need to store a single object by id: `food` -> `food[index]`.

Comment: Hi @mkobuolys thanks you. I did the same as you have done in code but it gave error, but now it works perfectly fine. Also I missed to generate type adapter for my model class hehe :) I sound stupid and need more sleep